# How to do login page first in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, yeoman-generator, angular-fullstack

I new with angularjs and I'm trying use this generator-angular-fullstack,

I want the page login first and not the main, I play with the code and my solution is to add 'authenticate: true' in MainCtrl

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      });
  });
```

and comment the line 'event.preventDefault();' in app.js in the run function

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          //event.preventDefault();
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    });
```

But I'm not sure is this changes are good or there are other best solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this, your code will be like this

in **main.js**

```
 angular.module('myapp')  
       .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          });   
      });
```

in **account.js**

```
    angular.module('myapp')
      .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/account/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          })
          .state('signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'app/account/signup/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupCtrl'
          })
          .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'app/account/settings/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
            authenticate: true
          });
      });
```

in **login.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $window) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = {};

    $scope.login = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.login({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        })
        .then( function() {
          // Logged in, redirect to home
          $location.path('/main');
        })
        .catch( function(err) {
          $scope.errors.other = err.message;
        });
      }
    };

    $scope.loginOauth = function(provider) {
      $window.location.href = '/auth/' + provider;
    };
  });
```